# Reading multiple checkbox value from cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, checkbox

I am able to set the cookie for check boxes using the jquery function below. I am using the map function for reading values into cookies and the cookie gets saved automatically.

But I am not able to read cookie and set checkbox value on page refresh. I need to set the checkboxes to checked/ unchecked based on cookie value. Thanks in advance.

### HTML Code

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="Option1" name="Option1" />
<input type="checkbox"  id="Option2" name="Option2" />
<input type="checkbox"  id="Option3" name="Option3" />
<input type="checkbox"  id="Option4" name="Option4" />
<input type="checkbox"  id="Option5" name="Option5" />
```

### Jquery part

```
var $checkboxes;
//set the cookie
function setcookie() {
    var options= $checkboxes.map(function() {
        if (this.checked) return this.name;
    }).get().join(',');
   $.cookie('new_cookie', options);

}

$(function() {
    $checkboxes = $('input:checkbox').change(setcookie);

});
```

Comment: is this functioning properly: $checkboxes = $('input:checkbox').change(setcookie);

Comment: yes..I set the alert($.cookie('the_cookie')); on page load, it shows the cookie value (Option1,Option3 etc), but the checkboxes aren't getting selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make cookies last longer even when browser closes or in multitabs. 
Try

```
var $checkboxes;
//set the cookie
function setcookie() {
    var options= $checkboxes.map(function() {
        if (this.checked) return this.name;
    }).get().join(',');
   $.cookie('new_cookie', options,{expires:1});

}

$(function() {
    $checkboxes = $('input:checkbox').change(setcookie);

});
```

And while loading or after refreshing page use

```
var alreadySetCookies= $.cookie('new_cookie').split(',');

for(var $cookie in alreadySetCookies) {
        $("input[name='" + alreadySetCookies[$cookie] + "']").attr("checked", "checked");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var $checkboxes = $('input:checkbox');

//set the cookie
function setcookie() {
    var options = $checkboxes.map(function () {
        if (this.checked) return this.name;
    }).get().join(',');
    $.cookie('new_cookie', options);
}

$checkboxes.change(setcookie);

$(document).ready(function () {

    var values = $.cookie('new_cookie').split(',');
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
    for(var $v in values) {
        $("input[name='" + values[$v] + "']").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to select the corresponding checkbox try this:

```
 var chk = $.cookie('the_cookie');

 $('#'+chk).prop('checked','checked');
```

or

```
$("'#"+chk+"'").prop('checked','checked');
```

not tried just assuming may be this helps.